# Sending Data from one page to another without using form php

Tags: php

How to send data from one page to another without using form?
I am getting id and type by **GET** method

```
 <a href="form.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']."&".$_GET['type']; ?>" class="orderbtn">Order Now</a>
```

When I go to *form.php*, I fill the form and click on the submit button my form page code is below

**form.php**

```
<div id="form">
  <p class="rf">*Required Fields </p>
  <form action="formsubmitted.php" onsubmit="return formValidate()" method="post" name="myform">
         <span class="required" title="Required Field">*</span>
         <span style="font-size:16px; color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Name: </span>  
         <input id="name" title="Enter Your Full Name" type="text" name="name" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" value=""/><br/>
          <span class="required" title="Required Field">*</span>
         <span style="font-size:16px;color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-right:10px;">Email:</span> 
         <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="xyz@example.com"/><br/>
          <span class="required" title="Required Field">*</span>
         <span style="font-size:16px;color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Address:</span>
         <input id="address" title="Enter Address" type="text" name="address" required="required" value=""/><br/>
         <span class="required" title="Required Field">*</span>
         <span style="font-size:16px;color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Contact Number:</span>
         <input id="contactno"  title="Enter Number" type="text" name="contact" required="required" value=""/><br/>
         <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></span>
   </form> 
</div>
```

When I submitted it goes to *formsubmitted.php* page where I am inserting data into database using post method i.e.

**formsubmitted.php**

```
   <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        $select_db = mysql_select_db("fashion",$connection);
        if(!$connection)
        {
            die ("Could not Connect".mysql_error());
        }

         $query = "INSERT INTO `order` (flname,email,address,contact) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['address']}','{$_POST['contact']}');";
     echo $query . "<br />";
     $res = mysql_query($query,$connection);
     if(!$res) {die("Could Not Enter Data".mysql_error());}
     else { echo "Enter Data Successfully."; }

     ?>
```

I want to insert the id and type which I am getting in the url in form page how can i do that?

Comment: I see inline-styling and usage of `mysql_query` both of which are bad practices in web design. I think you should be concerned about those for now.

Comment: Your code provides an excellent example of how to construct dangerous SQL queries.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: yes u both r rights but next time i will be surely not doing that designing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `&type=`

```
 <a href="form.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']."&type=".$_GET['type']; ?>" class="orderbtn">Order Now</a>
```

...................................................................................................^

You need use to `$_GET` in form.php

```
 <?php   $id = $_GET['id'];
         $type = $_GET['type'];
  ?>

     <form action="formsubmitted.php" onsubmit="return formValidate()" method="post" name="myform">
    ......
      <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
      <input name="type" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $type;?>">
    </form>
```

in formsubmitted.php:

```
 <?php echo $_POST['id']; echo $_POST['type']; ?>
```

Comment: i do that but it is inserting the id value in type coloumn in database and id is 0 when a new record is added..

Comment: in formsubmitted.php, use print_r($_POST); to verify the posted value

Comment: it is printing now like this

Array ( [name] => Imran Mushtaq [email] => imi.mushtaq@gmail.com [address] => 3280y28y [contact] => 73427343 [id] => 7 [type] => winter [submit] => Submit ) 

but the same problem id colomn=0 and Type colomn has the value of id...

Comment: [id] => 7 [type] => winter, it carried and posted the proper values.

Comment: how you say id=0 ? can you show your formsubmitted.php file source'

Comment: formsubmitted.php
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 $select_db = mysql_select_db("fashion",$connection);
 if(!$connection)
 {
  die ("Could not Connect".mysql_error());
 }
  
  
  
  $query = "INSERT INTO `order` (flname,email,address,contact,Type,id) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['address']}','{$_POST['contact']}','{$_POST['id']}','{$_POST['type']}');";
 echo $query . "<br />";
 $res = mysql_query($query,$connection);
 if(!$res) {die("Could Not Enter Data".mysql_error());}
 else { echo "Enter Data Successfully."; }

 ?>

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO order (flname,email,address,contact,Type,id) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['address']}','{$_POST['contact'‌​]}','{$_POST['type']}', '{$_POST['id']}') ";`

Comment: You have shuffled the id and its respective post value in query, i have modified in above, please use it

Comment: hmm it works .. I am thinking the colomn name type is after id thats why i am inserting values in that sequence...
but thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can send this params in a hidden field As this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="<?php echo $_GET['type'];?>"/>
```

And you need to add protection against XSS